# When to focus first element in ItemsControl after data-binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl control which is data-bound to a list. In the ItemsControl is a DataTemplate which displays all data-bound items as buttons.

Now I want the first button to receive focus.

When do set the focus? Doing this in the ContentRendered and DataContextChanged events don't work the controls don't seem to be rendered at that point.

Bonus question: what's the best way to look up such a button on my window?

Comment: Focus on First element of `ItemsControl` or Focus on First Button?

Comment: The button of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the **DataContextChanged** event doesn't work because the DataContext actually changes before the ObservableCollection you are binding to has any content.

I haven't had a chance to test it, but just a thought, perhaps you could try setting the focus in the [TargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler on your binding to your **ItemsSource**.

The only issue with this is that if the collection continues to update then the focus will continually return to the first button, but this is something you can handle with a simple flag.